# Accept Payments in Desktop Application

Tags: java, payment, rfid, payment-processing

I'm creating a java application to manage rentals. I need to be able to scan RFIDs, which made me lean towards creating a desktop application (so that I could easily interface with a USB connected RFID scanner). I also need to accept credit card payments in this application. Every gateway / API I've found (Braintree, Stripe, etc.) is tailored either for mobile development or use on a website. How can I accept payments on my application, or is there a platform that would be better for my needs(RFID scanning and accepting payments)?

Thanks!

Comment: show us your implementation

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this - my implementation of what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a module to desktop application that will connect with a web service hosted centrally which is under control of payment receiver. This web service can in turn make calls to payment gateway.
A web service client module within your desktop application doesn't need to store any sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

- "RFID scanning and accepting payments" - these are very different things that have nothing to do with each other.  I'll assume from the question title you want to know about payments.
- You probably don't want to do what you are asking at all.

Charging a person's credit card is something that needs to be done with care and proper security.  If you use an online payment gateway (authorize.net or some such thing), in order to take payments you will need to receive authentication information (i.e. some sort of username/password or API key or something) that allows you to do this (it is, through whatever payment gateway, linked to your bank account, etc.)  It is a major security problem to do this inside your application - since the sensitive information necessary would be able to be recovered (regardless of how much you obfuscate or encrypt the data - if your code can read it, and the user has your code, you are screwed).  This means that someone other than you would be able to just charge people's credit cards to our account, or refund people, etc.

I would suggest simply using a regular web browser and taking the payments online.

If you need "RFID scanning support" - you can probably do this by getting a reader that just emits keystrokes (people have been doing that with barcode readers for probably more than 30 years) and types the number into a text field on your web page.  You don't describe your application's use so it's hard to say if that's workable for you - but that's likely much more the direction you want to go.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of description on where I'm trying to go: on the whole, I'm trying to create an application to manage gear that I'm renting out - so I want to tag the equipment with RFIDs, then be able to check it out / in by scanning the RFIDs. I also want to be able to charge customers in this process (which is why I was looking for ways to handle payment). Thanks so much for the advice! I'll look into the keystroke reader idea - if I can find one that would probably work, as I'd be able to do the whole thing in the browser and just use Braintree.

Comment: Cool, sounds good.  Please remember to upvote answers you find helpful and accept correct ones.

Comment: Alright, thanks for help! Ended up deciding on taking the payments online with Braintree and am working on getting the keyboard mimicking rfid scanner ( waiting on delivery). Don't have enough rep to upvote yet (new user).